# I get this error (ValueError: The parameter loc has invalid values) that aborts training of my agent. The environment is openai's pendulum

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The environment is Pendulum from OpenAI Gym. Pytorch 1.9.1+cu102 is the package used for training the model.

This error occurs around the code :

```
out = Lorian(torch.tensor(observation))
distro = torch.distributions.Normal(out[0],torch.absolute(out[1]))
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythons\pendulum\Main1.py", line 90, in <module>
    distro = torch.distributions.Normal(out[0],torch.absolute(out[1]))
  File "C:\Users\Mukundan1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\distributions\normal.py", line 50, in __init__
    super(Normal, self).__init__(batch_shape, validate_args=validate_args)
  File "C:\Users\Mukundan1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\distributions\distribution.py", line 53, in __init__
    raise ValueError("The parameter {} has invalid values".format(param))
ValueError: The parameter loc has invalid values
```

the object 'distro' is sampled to get the agent's decision given the current observation. `Lorian` is the name of this model/neural network.
The output of the neural network can be either positive and negative but the standard deviation from mean can only be a positive since `torch.absolute(out[1])` is used.

Before I started using the absolute value of `out[1]` the error was mostly the same except instead of `'loc'` it said `'scale'`.

Where is the mistake in my input of `torch.distributions.Normal()`?

Comment: Can you print out `out[0]`? Also, which version of PyTorch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can "print" the output of the neural network.May be your output is 'nan' that case the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).